# TTask.Waitforall produces "At least one task in thread array nil" error

Tags: android, delphi

I am working in Delphi 10.1.2 on an Android Service project. I have followed the available examples for managing TTask.Run threads. I have tried the code both with an `Array of ITask` and `TList<ITask>` but the error is the same.

```
{$define TASK_ARRAY}

{$ifdef TASK_ARRAY}
  TaskArray: Array of ITask; 
{$else}
  TaskList: TList<ITask> // has the same problem
{$endif}
```

The creation of the threads is asynchronous and actually driven by the GPS...

```
procedure TMainService.SendNewPosition(Username: String; NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D;
  PosTimeStamp: TDateTime; UseColor: TAlphaColor);
var
  ATask: ITask;
begin
...

ATask := TTask.Create(procedure
begin
  // a small procedure that runs very quickly
  // but which is called very frequently
end
);
if ATask <> nil then // trying to eliminate the problem
begin
  {$ifdef TASK_ARRAY}
    SetLength(TaskArray, Length(TaskArray) + 1);
    TaskArray[High(TaskArray)] := ATask;
  {$else}
    TaskList.Add(ATask);
  {$endif}
  ATask.Start;
end;
```

A little later, in the `AndroidServiceTrimMemory` event handler, I do this:

```
   var
     i: Integer;
     ATask: ITask;
   begin
     try
       {$ifdef TASK_ARRAY}
         i := High(TaskArray);
         // try to delete any nil ITask before WaitForAll finds it
         while i > -1 do
         begin
           ATask := ITask(TaskArray[i]);
           if ATask = nil then // never happens
           begin
             Delete(TaskArray,i,1); 
             i := High(TaskArray);
           end
           else
             Dec(i);
         end;
         TTask.WaitForAll(TaskArray, Wait);
         SetLength(TaskArray, 0);
       {$else}
         TTask.WaitForAll(TaskList.ToArray, Wait);
         Tasklist.Clear;
       {$endif}
     except
     on e: exception do
       Log(e.Message); // 'At least one task in array nil'
     end;
```

Now I have had the chance to trace into `TTask.WaitforAll`, and `TTask.DoWaitForAll`, to see where the exception is raised:

```
for I := High(Tasks) downto Low(Tasks) do
begin
  Task.Value := TTask(Tasks[I]);
  if Task.Value = nil then
    raise EArgumentNilException.CreateRes(@sWaitNilTask);
```

When the error is raised, `I` is sometimes 1 and sometimes 0. `High(Tasks)` is maybe 4 or 5. The error occurs on every run.

All and any comments are appreciated.

** edit after Remi's comment**

I copied the system.threading to my project and made a small change to DoWaitForAll (the overload with a timeout)

```
var
  ATask: ITask;
...
  for I := High(Tasks) downto Low(Tasks) do
  begin
    ATask := ITask(Tasks[I]); // casts correctly
    if ATask <> nil then
    begin
      Task.Value := TTask(Tasks[I]); // doesn't cast correctly
      if Task.Value = nil then
        raise EArgumentNilException.CreateRes(@sWaitNilTask);
```

This is all a bit over my head. But maybe someone else understands what's happening here?

Comment: The code you have shown does not store any nil pointers in your array or `TList`. However, as you quoted, `DoWaitForAll()` is type-casting each `ITask` to `TTask` without using the `as` operator.  Such a type-cast returns a `nil` object pointer if the object being referenced by the interface is not the specified class type. Which would imply that either the array you pass to `WaitForAll()` does not contain interface references to `TTask` objects (which it does), or the type-casts are failing (bad RTTI, etc). You will have to keep debugging so see what the type-casts are really doing.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks. I have dug a bit deeper and added to my question.

Comment: you didn't really dig much deeper into it at all. I meant for you to debug into the actual RTL code behind the `TTask(Tasks[I])` cast (interface reference to object reference). I suspect that to be broken in Android (maybe all ARC platforms). The `ITask(Tasks[I])` cast (interface reference to interface reference) is basically a no-op since `Tasks[I]` is already an `ITask`.

Comment: In all sincerity, debugging the RTL code is a bit beyond my skill and experience right now. (I did what I can understand to do)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone followed this question, I just wanted to describe the solution I adopted. ie. this is the answer to my application problem, not the answer to my question. Instead of an `Array of ITask` or a `TaskList: TList<ITask>`, I used:

```
FThreads: TObjectList<TThread>;
```

...

```
constructor TMainService.Create(Owner: TComponent);
...
  FThreads := TObjectList<TThread>.Create(True);
  AThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
  begin
    // this dummy thread does nothing
  end
  );
  AThread.FreeOnTerminate := False;
  FThreads.Add(AThread); // so ARC won't throw FThreads away (it happened!)
```

...

```
procedure TMainService.SendNewPosition(Username: String; NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D;
PosTimeStamp: TDateTime; UseColor: TAlphaColor);
var
  AThread: TThread;
  ...
  AThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure
  begin
    // a small procedure that runs very quickly
    // but which is called very frequently   
  end
  );
  AThread.FreeOnTerminate := False;
  FThreads.Add(AThread);
  AThread.Start;
```

A little later, in the AndroidServiceTrimMemory event handler, I do this:

```
i := 1; // preserve the dummy thread reference
while i < FThreads.Count do
begin
   AThread := FThreads.Items[i];
   AThread.WaitFor;
   Inc(i);
end;
// delete all but the dummy thread [0]
while FThreads.Count > 1 do
begin
  i := FThreads.Count - 1;
  FThreads.Delete(i);
  FThreads.TrimExcess;
end;
```